# Is it necessary to use static method and property in this class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I'm studying OOP in PHP. And I'm confused about using `static` methods and properties.

In this example I will use a little cache example on server side. But I'm not sure to use static method and property.

```
class Villa extends CI_Model
{
  // Cache
  protected $cacheOwner;

  ...   

  public function owner()
  {
   if ( ! empty($this->cacheOwner))
        return $this->cacheOwner;
```

I think it will work but to use "static" is better? Or I must use "static" only when inherits a property or method from a parent class?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because answers appear to be mostly opinion-based

Comment: Do you understand what the difference between static and non-static properties and methods is?

Comment: `I think it will work but to use "static" is better?` So why is that better?

Comment: I m trying to learn when I must use static methods and properties

Comment: Bear in mind that "static" means that if you instantiate the class again within the same process, the value will be the same as the last one until you explicitly reset it. This is useful in some cases (e.g. singletons) but generally not for ORM models.

Comment: @halfer Thanks halfer. If I dont instantiate the class again within the SAME process, I will never use static. Am I right?

Comment: Well, a static attribute is read at the class level, so you could read it from `Villa::$cacheOwner` if it were static and public (and with a method if it is static and protected). So, you can use static attributes even without instantiating the class once.

Comment: Do you want one `cacheOwner` per `Villa` row (assuming that this class is a ORM row class)? If so, then you don't want this to be static.

Comment: Also remember that, `static` should be avoided, `anti-pattern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm studying OOP in PHP. And I'm confused about using static methods
>   and properties.
>
> In this example I will use a little cache example on server side. But
>   I'm not sure to use static method and property

So, how to create and use static method/properties :

```
class Villa extends CI_Model
{
    protected static $cacheOwner = null;

    public static function owner()
    {
        if ( ! is_null(static::$cacheOwner) ) {
            return static::$cacheOwner;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it as

```
Villa::owner();
```

> I think it will work but to use "static" is better? Or I must use
>   "static" only when inherits a property or method from a parent class?

No, it's not right at all because static considered `harmful` and `anti-pattern`. In the term `object oriented programming` where `Objects` encapsulate state and provide methods to transform this state but when you use `static` properties and methods it violates the principle because it (static) preserves the same state on all instantiated objects and hence it's a `class oriented programming`, not `OOP`. In `OOP` classes are just blueprints/data type and objects are the things that comes in to play. Also static methods/classes doesn't facilitate unit testing because of hard dependency and also hard to extend. In some cases like singleton [design pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html), static class methods/properties are probably useful but it's (singleton) itself considered a bad design pattern and out of `OOP`. Check [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and other links provided in (See also) section.

So, try to avoid `static` and finally, none can tell you what actually you need in your class but you, because you know what you are going to do and how is your class related with your application and if you need to maintain the same state of a property/data all the way to your application's lifetime then you may use it but not sure. Also, check [this search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20OOP) and read some good answers, you'll learn a lot from here, at least I did a lot and i found [this article](http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html) with some examples, could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will use a static method if the method does not make use of variables local to an instantiated object of the given class the method is contained within.